# es6 map failed to render, no error in console

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my render function I do console.log(items) I got this

[image]

but why my rendering output nothing?

```
{items.map(item => {
    <li key={item.id}>item.name</li>
})}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a return statement in the body of the arrow function, and also curly braces around `item.name`, the required syntax for interpolation in JSX.

```
{items.map(item => {
      return <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
//    ^                        ^         ^
})}
```

Take a look at [JSX In Depth](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html), which has lots of details you might find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
{items.map(item => {
    <li key={item.id}>item.name</li>
})}
```

This doesn't return the `<li />` from the map function. What you need is:

```
{items.map(item => <li key={item.id}>item.name</li>)}
```

which returns `<li />` implicitly or do:

```
{items.map(item => {
   return <li key={item.id}>item.name</li>
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about return)

```
   {items.map(item => {
        return <li key={item.id}>item.name</li>
    })}
```

or can write like this

```
 {items.map(item => <li key={item.id}>item.name</li>  )}
```